# When using a shell script, minecraft/java throws errors

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, java, minecraft

Basics:

1. This is a learning experience, I am new and doing this to expand my knowledge.  So if you can please explain in detail...it would be appreciated.
2. This is a new install of Ubuntu Server, it is up to date.
3. I have the latest version of OpenJDK 8 installed.
4. I have a forge version of Minecraft (1.12.2) installed; latest forge.
5. I can start the minecraft server in the command line using:

   `java -Xms1024M -Xmx4096M -jar forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2854.jar nogui`
6. When trying to us a script (.sh) minecraft starts, but then throws out errors about cataloging files and crashes me out of the ssh session.

   ```
   #!/bin/sh

   java -Xms1024M -Xmx4096M -jar forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2854.jar nogui
   ```

The script is in the directory for the minecraft program, it does start.  what I do not understand is, with the exact same format that works, this does not.  So...I can only conclude I am missing something that is key, but is not covered in the tutorials and research that I have done to this point.  I could use some assistance please.  Thank you for your time.

edit 1: After a bit of thought in my wayback archives, here you are, the results of my using the script: https://pastebin.com/61Nfb5CQ

Could the errors be caused by the script not running with inadaquit permissions?

edit 2: After adding the sudo command to the script I got his: https://pastebin.com/V6pJyCvj  Result...still did not run...but did not run as badly.  Oh and here is the file directory maybe something here https://imagebin.ca/v/5PjVcSb4D5OA

Comment: It would help a lot if you show the exact error that you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error seems to be related to not having enough permissions. This is likely due to you not using `sudo` at the start of the line. This is required for Minecraft to operate as intended. There are mulitple instances in your code that go as follows:

```
2020-06-11 09:50:54,060 main ERROR Cannot access RandomAccessFile java.io.FileNotFoundException: logs/debug.log (Permission denied) java.io.FileNotFoundException: logs/debug.log (Permission denied)
```

Notice how it says `(Permission denied)` in some parts of the log. This is because, as the name implies, you don't have permission to do the requested task. This is usually taken care of by using `sudo` to gain root priviliges.

In your case, the correct code would be:

```
#!/bin/sh

sudo java -Xms1024M -Xmx4096M -jar forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2854.jar nogui
```

At the start of the program's execution, it will ask you for your password in order to gain root priviliges. This is perfectly normal.

Comment: Sidenote: It is not required, but I would recommend upgrading your OpenJDK version. Major update versions of Java are guaranteed to contain performance, stability, and security updates. The latest current OpenJDK version is ```OpenJDK 14```.

Comment: Minecraft and it's mods only support 8.  I have tried 11 and 14 on other platforms and it does not work from what I tried.  As for the post, I was thinking that...is there a way to automate the sudo process to include a PW entry?

Comment: Ok, that's fine. As long as it works, it works. Did the above command work for you, or not?

Comment: I am at work...so I can not test until later.  Will inform when I do.

Comment: OK, updated, it worked less badly.  New log added to main post.

Comment: For one, it looks like something is passing invalid arguments to the server. Second, it appears as if the server is alternating between openjdk 8 and 12 inside of the execution cycle. Normally this doesn't and shouldn't happen. Do you have any other openjdk installations? Try and remove those even if it is setup to use openjdk 8.

Comment: I only have openjdk 8. It is all I installed and when I checked there were no other jdk's on the machine.  And it is odd as it is the same command I use as user...and everything starts fine.

Comment: The openjdk 12 part is my bad. It only uses 8. I got it mixed up with server version 12. I don't know why it would behave this way. Have you tried reinstalling the server (Make sure to save your mods and other important files if you do)?

Comment: Could it be a difference in permissions?  I know I am using sudo in the script, but the script, the forge.jar, and other files all have different permission sets.

Comment: Ok, found the answer.  Looks like in this case the interpreter was the problem.  After removing '#!/bin/sh' it started.  Interesting...but hey if it works.

Comment: I never thought switching from sh to bash would make a difference. Glad it worked for you! If my answer helped you, please to mark it as accepted.

Comment: Thank you for the help!  Much appreciated.

Comment: @SyberSmoke No problem! A pleasure to help!

Answer (score 0):

Your script `run1.sh` is trying to access/modify some file which is protected or even trying to create a file into a protected folder.
your have two options from this point:

1. Execute this script as `sudo`.
2. Take a look in this script and give permissions only for the necessary folder/files.